# how to start my own application from the native android contactdetails page?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-widget

I am taking the reference of one application from android market  and i want a similar interface actually so the actual problem goes like this see-->

Step 1.)    We have our native contact list in android Phone right please see the screen shot attched---->

![enter image description here][1]

step2.)Now i select a Particular Contact from this contact List Lets say I select xyz so we will
reach to the following Page see---->
![enter image description here][2]
On click of a contact Page.
On this Page the Call mobile option is the default one of the android Phone but after that there is a second row
coming with the option of Walkie-talkie thats the customised one by the application developer now when you click on that walkie talkie then it starts your application screenshot attached as----->

on click of the walkie talkie
![enter image description here][3]

now it lands to the application.

Now the thing is where should i make changes to add that option of walkie talkie to start your own  application.
like here they gave Walkie talkie on the contact details page the similar option i want to give for my application also
then where should i give this option??

1)We cannot make the changes in the OS files as it is the application.
2)There Must be some option in the android-manifest.xml file to give this option of putting a new row to start
our own application from the android Native Contact Details Page.I tried googling it but could not figure out much.

3) See there are intents to interact with the native Phone call or SMS so like that only for example to send the sms on click on call phone we can do like this to move it to our application like if you click on call Mobile then we are able to give options like see ----->

```
        <activity
        android:name=".KVSMSLiteActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter android:label="Send Voice SMS">
            <action  android:name="android.intent.action.CALL_PRIVILEGED"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:scheme="tel" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter android:label="Send Voice SMS">
            <action  android:name="android.intent.action.SENDTO"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:scheme="sms" />
            <data android:scheme="smsto" />
        </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

enter code here like this....
on click on the call mobile

if you click on dial it goes to android native phone call and if you click on Send Voice SMS then it goes to my application for this what they did is see in the android-manifest.xml file for mail activity they putted this option---->

So can you Please suggest me how i can put a new row after the android native call Mobile row.....??
![enter image description here][4]
finally how to do this

Thanks for giving your time.....:-)

Regards,
Narendra.

Comment: [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/LJKzN.png

Comment: [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/RRikT.png
  [2]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/CEesC.png
  [3]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/ZkbMW.png

Comment: i was not able to post images so putted in the comments please click on URL and see them and help me.

Comment: Hi Keyser i am getting an error saying Oops! Your question couldn't be submitted because:

    * Please add some context to explain the code sections (or check that you have not incorrectly formatted all of your question as code).

Comment: after giving the description for each images i am not able to do so....:-(

Comment: can you please look at my problem and try to open the images??

Comment: It's probably due to your low reputation. I guess you're not allowed to post images in questions. Sry, can't help with the question. But put the links in the question. Just don't embed.